# Adding a score from a list in python programming

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

```
 aliens = ['red_alien', 'blue_alien', 'blue_alien', 'green_alien', 
'red_alien', 'red_alien', 'red_alien', 'blue_alien', 'blue_alien', 
'green_alien'] 

current_score = 0

for alien in aliens:
    if 'red_alien' in aliens:
        current_score += 5

    elif 'green_alien' in aliens:
        current_score += 10

    elif 'blue_alien' in aliens:
        current_score += 20

print(current_score)
```

Currently, I'm unsure why the numbers aren't adding up correctly when the code is being run.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over aliens with "alien"
So you can just compare `'red_alien' == alien`
that should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You loop over `aliens` assigning each element to `alien`. But then you test if `red_alien` is in `aliens` (note the s) which is the **whole** list, not the `alien`. I think what you want is:

```
current_score = 0

for alien in aliens:
    if 'red_alien' == alien:
        current_score += 5

    elif 'green_alien' == alien:
        current_score += 10

    elif 'blue_alien' == alien:
        current_score += 20

print(current_score)
```

Comment: your tabs are off in the ifs

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following code. It may not provide additional benefits but still, it's another way of writing the same code.

```
alien_list= {'red_alien':5, 'green_alien':10, 'blue_alien':20}
current_score= 0
for alien in aliens:
    if alien in alien_list.keys():
        current_score += alien_list[alien]

print(current_score)
```

output:
`120`